# ElasticSearch doesn't match underscore values

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to do search by file names and some files usually have `_` in name.
ElasticSaarch doesn't return files with `_`

I have file with name `file_example_ODS_100.ods`. When I try to search is by query string `file_example` it doesn't return me this file.

My query:

````
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "fields": [ "name^2", "combined_folders^2" ],
                            "query": "' . $queryParams['query'] . '",
                            "max_expansions": 50,
                            "fuzziness": "2",
                            "lenient": true,
                            "analyzer": "standard",
                            "prefix_length": 1,
                            "operator": "AND",
                            "minimum_should_match": "20%"
                        }
                    }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match" : 1
                }
              } ```
````

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

Maybe you are using the default `standard` analyzer on your field that stores `file_example_ODS_100.ods` which tokenize it based on `.` as shown in the analyze API response.

```
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "file_example_ODS_100.ods"
}
```

**Resultant tokens**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "file_example_ods_100",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 20,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "ods",
            "start_offset": 21,
            "end_offset": 24,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

### Solution

In this case, searching for `file_example` isn't matching the tokens generated during index time, in order to get result for that, you can use the [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) as shown below

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix" : { "<your-field>" : "file_example" } //replace your-field with your actual field.
  }
}
```